# User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from User profile application - Cant access application either

Tags: error, security, central-administration, service-application, application-pool

I am experiancing an issue where ever so often the sharepoint (2010) site keeps throwing security errors(The security validation
            for this page is invalid)  iisreset fixes this shortly but the problem keeps coming back. Running the correlation ID gives the following error:

*User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from Us
           er Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserPro
           fileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application av
           ailable to service the request.*

Research has showed that this could be caused by the user profile service application and strangly when trying to access this via central admin i get more errors.

*User Profile Application Proxy failed to retrieve partitions from Us
           er Profile Application: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserPro
           fileApplicationNotAvailableException: No User Profile Application av
           ailable to service the request.*

*This User Profile Application's connection is currentl
           y not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may no
           t have been started.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually have the UPSA created in the Central Admin  -Service Applications? In the same place, check in Services On Server and make sure you have User Profile Service started (ideally also the User Profile service synchronization - not a must for your error to dissapear, but important for your fully-functional synchronization of user data).

If it is the case - but still you get that error (though i doubt it) you can Delete the UPSA, (reboot - optional but it would really help) and re-create it - this should also start the appropriate service.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Reboot is a bit of an overkill. `IISRESET` and restarting the sharepoint timer job should suffice.